# Proving $(x-c)|(p(x)-p(c))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

> Let $F$ be a field. $(x-c)|(p(x)-p(c))$.

So if $x-c|p(x)=q(x)-\frac{r}{x-c}$ so for $x-c|p(x)-p(c)=s(x-c)-\frac{r}{x-c}$. Is that correct? Or is there a different way to go about proving this? I have proved that $x-c|p(x)$ has a remainder of $p(c)$ so It wuld make sense that $p(x)-p(c)$ would be $x-c$.

Answer (score 4):

If you divide $p(x)$ with $x-a$ you get such polynomials $k(x)$ and $r(x)$ (remainder theorem) that
$$ p(x)=k(x)(x-a)+r(x)$$ 
Since $r(x)$ must be constant and previous formula is true for all $x$ it is also for $x=a$. Thus you get $r(x)=r(a)=p(a)$. So we have $$p(x)-p(a)=k(x)(x-a)$$ 
Thus $x-a$ divide $p(x)-p(a)$ if $p\in F[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(p(x)-p(c))=q(x)$ then $q(c)=0$ then because $F$ is a field so $x-c$ should devide $q(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Use the constant remainder theorem:
Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$, then the remainder of the division of any polynomial $g(x)\in F[x]$ by $x-c$ is $g(c)$. This implies that:

$$ x-c\,\big\vert\, f(x) \quad \text{if and only if} \quad f(c)=0 $$
then you can apply it to the polynomial $f(x)$ defined as: 
$$f(x)=p(x)-p(c)$$