# If $5|P(2),2|P(5)$ then which of the followings divides $P(7)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

> Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.If $5|P(2),2|P(5)$ then which of the followings divides $P(7)$?
>   a)10
>   b)7
>   c)3
>   d)4
>   e)8

$5|P(2),2|P(5)\Rightarrow5-2|p(5)-p(2)$ but this doesn't help.I don't know any property of polynomials useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a)

We know that for arbitrary $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have $$x-y\mid p(x)-p(y)$$

For a proof of this take a look at [Proving $(x-c)|(p(x)-p(c))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521462/proving-x-cpx-pc/2521466#2521466)

So we have $$5= 7-2|p(7)-p(2)$$ so $5\mid p(7)$ and $$2=7-5|P(7)-p(5)$$ so $2\mid p(7)$ thus $10\mid p(7)$.

---

**And we can say much more**: if $a\mid p(b)$ and $b\mid p(a)$ then $ab\mid p(a+b)$ if $a,b$ are relatively prime. The proof is exactly the same as for $a=2$ and $b=5$.

Comment: For a proof of that statement look at here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521462/proving-x-cpx-pc/2521466#2521466

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2 = 7 - 5 \mid P(7)-P(5)$ and $5 = 7 - 2 \mid P(7) - P(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Meta-solution**

There are no restriction on the degree of your polynomial.

If you take the constant polinomial $P(x)=10$ the conditions required are satisfied.

So the only coherent answer is $a)$

Comment: Very neat and quick. In some situations, speed is very important. Of course, this does not show that *a)* is the correct answer, but it does show that all the other given answers are wrong.

Comment: In fact is a meta-solution, not a solution! :D